# If G is a group then intersection of each non-trivial subgroup of G like K with subgroup H is non-trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

I came across this question and I can't figure it out.

Full problem is:

> Suppose the order of each non-trivial member of non-trivial group G is
> infinite. Prove that if H is a subgroup of G with finite index then
> intersection of each non-trivial subgroup of G like K with H is
> non-trivial.

All I could figure it out by myself is that in a group the intersection of an infinite subgroup with a finite index subgroup is infinite. but I don't know what to look for in next steps.

Comment: What is "like $K$"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde "subgroup of G (we name it K)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Here's a hint: Since $H$ is finite index in $G$, there are only finitely many cosets
$H, g_1 H, g_2 H, \ldots, g_n H$, and each $g \in G$ is a member of (exactly one) coset.

To say that $K \cap H$ is nontrivial, we want to find some $k \neq e \in K$ so that $k \in H$.

So fix some $k \neq e \in K$. We know $k, k^2, k^3, k^4, \ldots$ are all distinct elements (since $k$ has infinite order). Can you use the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) (where the "holes" are the cosets of $H$) to get what you want?

---

I hope this helps ^_^